# Does dynamically prefetching a resource using DOM injection work or make sense?

Tags: javascript, html, prefetch

This is largely a theoretical question, for which I do have a practical purpose. I first am looking for some conceptual answers before diving into practice, as perhaps the idea itself does not make sense.

Imagine a slideshow that is entirely javascript-based. Users see a large image on their screen and click to move to the next large image. Upon clicking, the next image is loaded and inserted into the DOM, replacing the previous one.

I recently learned that prefetching directives can help in speeding up the loading of resources that are very likely to be used next. Note that I said resources, not pages. The slideshow is a single page.

In an image slideshow, it is very obvious that it is likely that the next image is needed, thus if image1 is on screen, I could dynamically add this to the DOM:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="http://img.mysite.com/img2.jpg">
```

My questions regarding this idea:

- Would it work at all? Do browsers accept this directive when it is dynamically inserted in the DOM at run-time? Would it trigger the prefetch?
- Is there a possibility of timing conflicts, where if prefetching would indeed work, it did not finish in time before the use does the "load" without prefetching? Obviously this can happen, but will it have unwanted side effects?
- Will specific events such as image onload still work correctly, or are they never triggered in the case of a successful prefetch (assuming it works at all)?

I did a lot of searching but I am unable to find answers on this specific situation of dynamically injected prefetch hints.

Comment: You can just do `(new Image()).src = url` and the browser will download the image. If you have appropriate cache headers, the image will be loaded from cache when the user clicks the Next button.

Comment: @blender I appreciate the answer, but that was not the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onload` always gets triggered, even if the image is coming from cache. You do not have to worry about timing effects or race conditions, any such behavior would be a browser bug.

As mentioned in comments, `rel=prefetch` is not the only way of achieving pre-fetching. It works though even when dynamically inserted into the DOM. After all, you could fetch the image without the `prefetch` attribute and hide it.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me enough confidence to give it a try. Not saying I don't believe you, but what is your source of knowing this works when injected in the DOM?

Comment: Thanks, that's a very useful article. Technically though, it does not mention prefetching resources dynamically, only prerendering them, which is different.

Comment: Section "Inject prefetch hints at runtime" is, to me, top-level and only happens to use prerender as an example.

Comment: You state that "It works though even when dynamically inserted into the DOM." This appears to only be true in Chrome. Can you clarify?